# How can I make this possible?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making a map.  I want the player to create a stone button but they are on adventure mode so i need a command that makes it possible to be placed on something so when they make the button it can be replaced with a button that can be placed on dirt.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/199411/how-can-i-allow-placement-of-certain-blocks-in-minecraft-adventure-mode) question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted? ([Gfycat Link](https://gfycat.com/SadBlandGoose))

This is the contraption I used:

[image: Contraption]

1 is **Repeat**, **Unconditional** and **Always Active**

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{id:minecraft:stone_button}],CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:dirt"]}
```

2 is **Repeat**, **Unconditional** and **Needs Redstone**

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{id:minecraft:stone_button}]}
```

3 is **Impulse**, **Unconditional** and **Needs Redstone**

```
/clear @p stone_button
```

4 is **Chain**, **Conditional** and **Always Active**

```
/give @p minecraft:stone_button 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:dirt"]}
```